# Google won't display with header

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I'm having an issue where my page will not display a google map when my nav is on the page. If I remove everything between the  the maps will populate on the entire page. I was under the impression it should just render in the #map-canvas element, and I should be able to set height and width on it to contain it and manipulate it.

I thought that the header, nav or wrapper might some how be over top and have tried setting explicit z-order.

Is there anything that sticks out to anyone that would be tripping this up?
Is there a better way to set the map to the element? Not on dom load?

This is the relevant code for my head, generated from google.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</head>
```

This is the relevant HTML.

```
<header>
<nav>
  <ul id="mainNav">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li class="listText">BlueHarvest, star wars is great</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="map-canvas">    
</div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
```

My relevant CSS

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    float:left;
}
#mainNav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#mainNav li {
    float: left; 
}
#mainNav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}    
#map-canvas{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What sets the width of the map-canvas div?

Comment: Why is there a wrapper inside your map?

Comment: @victor that is an error from where I was tinkering. Doesn't work inside or out.

Comment: @geocodezip No width set, just tried one in px and %. No luck :(

Comment: Could you add your code to a jsfiddle, it's hard to debug it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to set a Height on my `<header>` or `<nav>`. ANY height, I tested from 1px-500px will set it correctly and display the Google map.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem last time I tried to implement Google Maps.  Try adding this to the end of your CSS:

```
.gm-style {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```